# Add object in pool with Apache Commons Pool 2

Tags: java, apache-commons-pool

I want to create a pool of Object P with Apache Commons Pool 2.
I create a P object with variable and method.

I create a PPool like this:

```
public class PPool extends GenericObjectPool<P>{

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * It uses the default configuration for pool provided by
     * apache-commons-pool2.
     * 
     * @param factory
     */
    public PPool(PooledObjectFactory<P> factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @param factory
     * @param config
     */
    public PPool(PooledObjectFactory<P> factory,
            GenericObjectPoolConfig config) {
        super(factory, config);
    }
}
```

And after that I create a PFactory:

```
public class PhantomJsFactory extends BasePooledObjectFactory<Phantom> {

    @Override
    public P create() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new P();
    }

    @Override
    public PooledObject<P> wrap(P phantomjs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new DefaultPooledObject<P>(phantomjs);
    }

}
```

Now if I want to add, for example, 10 instances of P object how do I do that?
I try with this:

```
        GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxIdle(1);
        config.setMaxTotal(10);


        config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        config.setTestOnReturn(true);
        pool = new PPool(new PFactory(), config);
```

but now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add the instances. You supply the Factory of the P class. So the Pool will manage object lifecycle. If you obtain object, it will be created by the Pool if it is required. Therefore just borrow the object to use.

```
P pObject = pool.borrowObject();
```

See description [GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject())

Please look at some test cases: [TestGenericObjectPool.java](https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-pool/+/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/TestGenericObjectPool.java)

Comment: but if i want for example 5 instance alway in execution? so when i borrow the object i have this 5 instance just ready

Comment: I think you can set minIdle to 5. then I think the pool will keep 5 instances in idle. I think you can borrow objects before to use in initialisation of your programme. `for (int i=0,l=config.getMinIdle(); i<l; ++i) pool.returnObject(pool.borrowObject());` You can check `pool.getNumIdle();`

Comment: See the testcase: https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-pool/+/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/TestGenericObjectPool.java find testMinIdle

Comment: Note that if you want to create objects automatically when there are no idle objects left you can call [BaseGenericObjectPool#setBlockWhenExhausted()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/BaseGenericObjectPool.html#setBlockWhenExhausted-boolean-)

Comment: Maybe off topic, but how can I initialise pool with pre-created objects. I have a list of available addresses and each thread borrows one address for its work...